# how to correctly modularize app configuration, so that tests(IT,datajpa,...) does not pick up everything intended for production

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-test

In our app I found out, that my integration tests picks up more stuff than I'd like. I'd like to know, how correctly structured app configuration looks like, what do you use, so that I can @Import in tests only those configuration which are used in production, which are needed.

I believe relevant page in documentation is:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-user-configuration

... it's stressed there, that it's important to structure code in sensible way, however it's not shown that much, what that is/means. I know about profiles and can probably create profile which would be unmatched in tests and import manually, but that's probably not that sensible way they were talking about.

Consider this main entrypoint:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    private final SomeService someService;

    public DemoApplication(SomeService someService) {
        this.someService = someService;
    }

    @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
    public void started() {
        System.out.println(someService.doIt());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

interface of some service:

```
public interface SomeService {
    public String doIt();
}
```

and configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class Config {
    @Bean
    public SomeService createSomeServiceBean() {
        return new SomeService() {
            @Override
            public String doIt() {
                return String.format("Hi! (At %s)", LocalDateTime.now());
            }
        };
    }
}
```

When invoked, entrypoint annotated by @SpringBootApplication will do component scan, will discover configuration and it will work. Reading further in documentation we will find sentence: `Test slices exclude @Configuration classes from scanning`([if @ComponentScan does have default value of basePackages and basePackagesClasses]), however following test:

```
@SpringBootTest
class DemoApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private SomeService someService;

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
        System.out.println(someService.doIt());
    }
}
```

just happily discovers `SomeService` bean defined. Or did that sentence meant just that tests annotated by for example @DataJpaTest won't register some configurations? Kinda unclear to me, but it does not seem possible, since how would @DataJpaTest would know, which configurations to ommit and which not.

Again, I know how to use profiles/excluding configurations. I'm asking about "sensible way of structuring app".

How to sensibly structure you app and how to configure it so that:

- `@SpringBootApplication` annotated entrypoint will do component scan, find and use configurations, for production, but these configurations needs to be manually imported in tests?
- some packages will be automatically scanned for configurations which will be used both in development and tests environments.

Answer (score 1):

The Spring Boot Test support provides annotations that allow to only create a Spring Context with the relevant beans to testing a specific *slice* of your application.

There is no specific package structure or naming strategy required to make use of this feature.

Here are some of these:

- `@DataJpaTest`: You get a Spring Context with relevant beans to test your JPA <-> Database interface: `EntityManager`, `DataSource`, all your interfaces extending `JpaRepository`
- `@WebMvcTest`: You get a Spring Context with a mocked servlet environment for testing your web layer that includes the following beans for your:  all your controller, controller advice, `WebMvcConfigurer` , `Filter`, etc. **but not** anything that is annotated with e.g. `@Service` or `@Component`
- `@SpringBootTest`: This will give you a full Spring Context and tries to create all beans for you. You can exclude some autoconfiguration e.g. if you don't want autoconfiguration to kick in:

Example:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = RANDOM_PORT)
@TestPropertySource(properties=
  {"spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration"})
```

- There are way more test slice annotations, you can have a look at [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications)

So these annotations are *smart* in a way that they know which beans they should include in the context and which to exclude.

A general approach to testing your application can be to use the first two test annotations stated above to verify web and data layer in isolation. Next use Mockito and plain JUnit 5 to unit test your service classes. And finally, write some integration test that creates the whole Spring Context with `@SpringBootTest` to test everything together.

Comment: I ± understand that, but quoted spring documentation page warns about using`@SpringBootApplication @ComponentScan({ "com.example.app", "org.acme.another" })`, saying: "Doing so effectively overrides the default component scan directive with the side effect of scanning those two packages... a @DataJpaTest seems to suddenly scan components and user configurations of your application." — So what I'm after is: how to import some configuration or how to extend scan paths to avoid that side-effect. I know surface-behavior of lots of annotations, but to solve this one needs really deep understanding…